# Using AdMob solely for House Ads

Tags: ios, admob, ads

I am updating one of my iOS apps to include Ads. However, I would only like to show own ads on contracts I sell to local companies. I believe AdMobs is a good enough for that since I can add my own "House ads", but I would like to "disable" AdMob to show any other ads from what I choose to show.

Is this possible? Or should I do this any other way, and if so.. how? (Any frameworks or services I can use?)

***EDIT***
To make my question a bit more clear: I believe I cannot use AdMob solely for house-ads, so how can I achieve using an external "partner" for house-ads only. Can it be done in the code for AdMobs, or should I use an other framework/partner?

Comment: What did AdMob say when you contacted them about this question about their product?

Comment: That's a terrible advice! [Stack Overflow is not a proxy for customer support](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128579/188419).

Comment: They seriously said "go post a question on StackOverflow" when you contacted them?  Or is that a joke?

Comment: Of course they didn't! My guess is that you know I didn't contact them, by how you wrote your counter-question. My question is not only "how to use admob", I believe I cannot do use only House Ads, but I would like to know how I otherwise could achieve my goal.

Comment: Haha, all right, just making sure ;)  That sounded a little odd to me!  I posted an answer that I hope will help you.  If I understand your question correctly, it should work fine :)

Comment: @WendiKidd its a joke, I was being Ironic... I think I failed ;)

Comment: I totally missed the irony and started looking all around meta.so for what to do when companies specifically send support issues here :-| I still think this sounds like a support issue, though.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your elaboration on your comment. I do not feel its an support issue. Also, I updated my question with a better description of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a product like [DoubleClick for Publishers](http://www.google.com/dfp/info/sb/index.html) where you can manage your own inventory.  DFP is also integrated with AdMob, so you can [use the AdMob SDK](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/ios/doubleclick/) to send requests to your DFP network.

Comment: Sounds promissing, I'll have a look! thnx

Comment: DoubleClick seems skewed towards websites. It requires that you have enough website content to qualify. A simple mobile app homepage will often not qualify. I have not figured out a way to get around this.

Comment: You can use DoubleClick (now known as Ad Manager) for apps only, but the barrier to entry on signing up for Ad Manager is higher. Honestly, AdMob is the right product for an app-only business until you start handling many deals. There are basic campaigns support in AdMob. AdMob will still show for inventory that you don't sell directly though, but it's unclear why you wouldn't want to monetize the rest of your users.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you only want to show House Ads and nothing else, then yes this can be done.

When you create an ad campaign, assign 100% of the ad allocation for your application to the house ads.  Then no paid ads will show up in your app.

Comment: Thank you! I have noticed that. But how do I solve the times I do not have an House Ad?

Comment: When you create a House Ad Campaign, you tell it how long to run.  Let's say you set the date for 6 months from now.  So for the next 6 months, those house ads will run.  After that, no ad will be returned and simply no ads will display.  (Personally I would suggest that you have a 'default' House Ad that points to your own website, that you can use when you have no other ads to display. But this isn't required.)

Comment: Ok, I'll have a deeper look into it. I believe, however, that when the 6 months are over, default AdMob Ads will be shown. I might be wrong, but I believe I looked into that option as well.

Comment: Would it be such a problem if they were?  1) You would get money for the ads that were shown.  2) You could always set up a calendar alert before the 6 months expired and set a new campaign to begin directly after. 3) I'm pretty sure you can set the campaigns for something like 2-3 years at a time.  (Just playing devil's advocate and trying to help ^^)

Comment: I understand your view, however these are the requirements I have on the app. Thank your for you thoughts, tho... very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Using AdMob you can achieve both third party advertising and sole house-ads using [Custom Events](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/custom-events). You can run fixed inventories of house-ads using *Impression Goal Campaigns*. If those house ad inventories run out AdMod we revert to eCPM based ad serving which will select the highest eCPM. To get sole house-ads add a new Custom Event in the AdMob management interface and set it's eCPM to something higher than what the *AdMob Network* would typically produce. See: [Ad sources ordered by eCPM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1gu2.png). Finally in Android implement your custom event as a class (com.appname.NoDisplayCustomEvent) inside your application to (1) show an AdMob ad, (2) show a hand made ad or (3) do nothing.

```
public class NoDisplayCustomEvent implements CustomEventInterstitial {
    CustomEventInterstitialListener listener;

    public void requestInterstitialAd(Context context, CustomEventInterstitialListener interstitialListener, String params, MediationAdRequest request, Bundle extra) {
        listener = bannerListener;

        if ( ... some criteria ...  )
            // Do custom event
            listener.onAdLoaded(); 
        else
            // Show AdMob
            listener.onAdFailedToLoad(AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL); 
    }

    public void showInterstitial() {
        listener.onAdOpened();
        listener.onAdClosed();
    }
    ...
```